# For loop not accessing and performing check

Tags: c++

I am having some troubles with one of my for loops not executing correctly. I have stepped through my code to try and see what's going on but it just seems to skip the for loop completely therefore giving the incorrect output.

My for loop looks like this:

```
for (auto &link : p1links){
            if (link->accessTransportType() != type){
                continue;
            }
            if ((p1->accessReference() == link->accessReferenceNumber1() && p2->accessReference() == link->accessReferenceNumber2()) || (p1->accessReference() == link->accessReferenceNumber2() && p2->accessReference() == link->accessReferenceNumber1()))
            {
                anyPASS = true;
            }
        }
        if (anyPASS){
            m_outFile << p1->accessReference() << "," << p2->accessReference() << "," << "PASS" << endl;
            return true;
        }
        else{
            m_outFile << p1->accessReference() << "," << p2->accessReference() << "," << "FAIL" << endl;
            return true;
            break;
        }
    }
    m_outFile << endl;
```

And these are the methods its trying to access when I say `accessTransportType()` etc.

```
class Links
{
    public:
    Links(int, int, const string&, bool);
    ~Links();

     int accessReferenceNumber1()const{ return referenceNumber1; }
     int accessReferenceNumber2()const{ return referenceNumber2; }
     string accessTransportType()const{ return transportType; }
     bool accessHasBeenSearched()const{ return hasBeenSearched; }

private:
    int referenceNumber1 = 0;
    int referenceNumber2 = 0;
    string transportType = "";
    bool hasBeenSearched = false;

};
```

My output is currently returning the FAIL every time but I am looking to return PASS for my first check and then a FAIL when it does the second check.

Comment: Does `p1links` actually contain any items, or is it empty?

Comment: @codran when I step through it equals { size=0 }

Comment: That would suggest that you have no links, so there's nothing to loop through. The code is behaving as it should.

Comment: @codran yeah, it should be equal to { size=2 }, any idea how I would fix this?

Comment: Wherever the problem lies, it lies well before the code snippets you have provided.

Comment: @codran I have a `Places.h` similar to the `Links.h` I have in my post where I call a `public: const vector<Links*>& accessLinks()const{ return links; }` in order to call a `private: vector<Links*> links;` within the same header file

Comment: @codran I have a feeling that the problem occurs on the line before my for loop when I am calling `vector<Links*> p1links = p1->accessLinks();` where it directs to the function I described in my previous comment